# JavaScript Event Handler on child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is that when I attach event handler on parent elements. It attached also to child elements. So, how to attach event to only parent. I tried `stopPropagation()/stopImmediatePropagation()` but neither works.

**HTML**

```
<div class="circle">
    <ul class="circle-child">
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".circle").click(function() {
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

And here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YgyTB/2/) demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event is only attached to the parent. But logically, since the child element is contained in the parent, if you click the child, you're also clicking the parent, and the handler fires because the event bubbles.

You can check to see if `this` (the item that the event was bound to) was the target of the event. Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/vtVpP/

```
$(".circle").click(function (e) {
    if (this === e.target) {
        console.log("clicked");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to apply the stop stopImmediatePropagation() to the child element. this will stop the event propagation from the child element.

```
$(".circle-child").click(function(e) {
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
})
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Gnb25/

Answer (score 0):

You may do this

```
<div class="circle">
    <ul class="circle-child">
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>  



$(".circle").click(function(e) {
    if($(e.target).is($(this)){
        console.log("clicked");
    }
});
```

But this will still call for child elements and check if the target is same as the listener

Comment: you don't need jquery object to check this & e.target

Answer (score 0):

You can always check to make sure the clicked element is what it's supposed to be by checking the event.target.

```
$('.circle').click( function(evt) {
    if ( $(evt.target).is('.circle') )
        alert("clicked");
});
```

Here is a revised [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VRkGm/) example.